# Better way to maintain an array of strings in C

Tags: c, pointers

Is there a better way to maintain a list of strings in C besides using typedef char* and declaring an array of type string? I am trying to manage a list of member names that join the group via socket program. But every time a new member joins the group - old member names get overridden. Part of the sample code is like this:

```
typedef char * string;
string  List[10];
```

and new member joins like this:

```
List[index]=membername;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean an auto-expanding array?

Comment: Sounds/looks like you have bugs in your code.  typedef is just an alias for a type - it won't solve design issues.  List is an array of pointers - you might be overwriting it with the wrong type ?

Comment: Why do older names get overridden? Are you forgetting to increment index?

Comment: How do you set `List[0]`? And `List[4]`? Show some relevant code!

Comment: @user629034 - Every new string received gets appended as the new element in the array. If this is what you want, *overridden* term is wrong to use in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably (not enough context) not allocating the strings properly.

```
string List[10];
```

only allocates an array of 10 `string`, i.e. 10 `char *`, i.e. 10 character pointers. It doesn't allocate any storage for the strings themselves.

So if your `membername` above is e.g. a global `char *` that you're copying data from the network to, all your slots in `List` will end up pointing to that *very same memory location*.

To make it work, you'd need to allocate (and carefully free) all the slots in `List`. Something like:

```
List[index] = strdup(membername);
```

For better chances of catching errors early, initially set your `List` to all null pointers.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) List[i] = NULL;
```

and when a user "goes away", free and reset that slot to NULL:

```
free(List[index]);
List[index] = NULL;
```

That way you'll get nice, nasty segfaults if you don't manage your slots carefully enough :-)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't allocating as you said enough space so strdup worked.

Comment: strings & char * are not the same thing.  Check K & R.  One is a character pointer , the other is a series of characters which is null terminated.

Comment: The question has `typedef char * string;`. In the question's context, string & char *, as far as types are concerned, are the same.

Comment: My apologies - this is so inane I missed that.  I was referring to "strings" in the K & R sense.

Answer (score 2):

With basic C-types you will need to have the List as a pointer-to-a-pointer and then for every new membername realloc it for another string (or have it set to a constant maximum amount of strings -- **which can cause nasty memory overruns** -- but if you modulate the index its safe).

- For every new membername you need to allocate a `char*` (c string) for this membername, if you only want to store this membername you can use `malloc(strlen(membername)+1)` to allocate it with space for the null terminated 0.
- When this is done you have memory to insert the string, do this by `strcpy(List[index++], membername)`.
- If you go for the static max amount of strings you have to use `strpcy(List[(index++)%ALLOCATEDSTRINGS,membername)`.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how `membername` is allocated. If it's a static string that you reuse, filling it with a new name every time one comes in, then you are overwriting the string multiple times. Storing the pointer to the string won't store the contents of the string, it will simply save its address.

To do this properly, you need to allocate (using `malloc()`) a new string for each new name. Each new string pointer is then assigned to a different member in the array.

Comment: Best, concise answer.  All the others are as subtle as having your leg sawn off.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an array of allocated char*, and if you need to, make it so you can dynamically grow the array.

So you'd have:

```
char **List = calloc(num_members,sizeof(char *));
```

Then when someone joins the group you'd have:

```
List[current_index] = calloc(strlen(new_user_name) + 1,sizeof(char));
strcpy(List[current_index++],new_user_name);
```

Keep in mind then that `num_members` would need to start big enough to handle as many members as may want to join, or you'd have to occasionally reallocate a bigger array.

Comment: Fixed it. I don't usually use arrays of strings, so I forgot.